# how to work with list view in asp?

Tags: asp.net

I want to generate a record of student. I use list view for display record, and also add a textbox. How will I get the value of those text box?

My code of list view is.

```
        <LayoutTemplate>

            <table>

                <th> id </th>
                     <th> name </th>
                <th> Value </th>

            <tr>
```

```
                 </table>
        </>

            </LayoutTemplate>

        <GroupTemplate>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="p2" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        </GroupTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("id") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("name") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox id="tx1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" /><br />
    <br />
```

I want insert my data on button click.

Comment: This is asp.net, not classic

Comment: then how to perform it

Comment: Can some body help plsssss